# To start/run an external executable and see its output logs

Tags: c++, qt, logging, qprocess

I run an external executable named `agent.exe` from within my Qt application like this:

```
// header
QProcess *m_agent;

// source
m_agent = new QProcess(this);

QString agentPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/agent.exe";

if (QFileInfo::exists(agentPath) && QFileInfo(agentPath).isFile()) {
    m_agent->start(agentPath);
} else {
    qDebug() << __func__ << "Executable does NOT exist\n";
}
```

---

My `agent.exe` runs fine by `QProcess *`, but the problem is that I cannot see its output logs. Is there is a way to see its logs?

Comment: What do you mean by output logs? You mean console output or the .log files?

Comment: @Gurushant Yes, I mean console output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect signal `readyReadStandardOutput()` of `QProcess` to a slot in your app and use the function `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` you will get the data in `QByteArray` form that you can either save in a `QFile` or show to user in a `QTextBrowser`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try out your solution ... let me try